# Installed Mint on external SSD, now Ubunty won't boot without SSD plugged in

Tags: dual-boot, external-hdd, mint

So, I installed Mint on an external SSD just because I had it laying around, and I found it entertaining to do so.

Now when I boot my laptop without the external Mint SSD plugged in, it goes to GRUB and won't boot Ubuntu.

Once Ubuntu boots with the SSD, I can eject and remove it, and the system continues to run absolutely fine. I don't want to have to lug the hard drive around with my laptop everywhere I go...

Comment: Sounds like the boot loader partition got installed to the external SSD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once booted into Ubuntu, unplug your external hard drive and run `sudo update-grub` and `sudo grub-install /dev/nvme0n1`

You can manually edit your `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` but this file will get overwritten when you run `update-grub`.

All the best!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, Balls!